# Create Iframe with the same Page and dynamically created tables

Tags: javascript

I've created I frame dynamically just like this:

```
link = window.location.href;
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

My page is just a local file.I have a table there.And I am copying that table with

```
cloneNode(true);
```

and inserting it with:

```
document.body.appendChild(newTable);
```

But in my Iframe this dynamycally created table doesn't exists.
So what should I do?

UPD: and another problem this works in chrome but in ie and firefox all Iframe Content  is empty just empty page

UPD2:

I just uppend Iframe and create it like this:

```
link = window.location.href;
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

In Ie and FF it shows empty page in Iframe.

Comment: Please add some more code, show the whole inserting line at least. In its current form your code definitely doesn't work in Chrome either.

Comment: I understood the question till the iframe appending part. I didn't understand the table part, and how it is related to your iframe. Are  you appending the table to your iframe, and then appending iframe to the main page? Please update question with more details.

Comment: See upd2, I have added some code

Comment: Looks like you're creating a kind of "infinite loop" here, when loading the same HTML to `iframe` as which you have in the main page. Within the newly created `iframe` browser will create a new `iframe`, within that `iframe`, a new `iframe` is created, etc. Appending `newTable` to `document.body` of the main page is definitely not appending a new table to a `iframe` in any browser. Notice, that especially in Chrome you can't even access the content of the `iframe` when using local files.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`importNode`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_importnode.asp) instead of `appendChild`.